# Set background image for listview with mutiple column

Tags: android, listview

I have to setup the background image for listview.Not setting image for each row.have to setup the background image for whole screen & select the radio button when list view load. that means first option should be selected

This is my code.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sales_routes);  // **Added edited**
    ArrayList<Object> routeList = getWmRoute();
    ArrayList<String> routhPath = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i<routeList.size();i++){
        routhPath.add(((WMRoute) routeList.get(i)).getDescription());
    }
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_two_column, R.id.FROM_CELL, routhPath));
    ListView list=getListView();
}
```

and my xml file is (list_two_column.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- row.xml -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingTop="4dip" 
    android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
     <!--android:background="@drawable/wallpaper" -->

    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </RadioButton>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/FROM_CELL" 
          android:layout_width="70dip"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Added Newly**   - sales_routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView 
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:dividerHeight="2dip"
        android:background="@drawable/wallpaper" />
</LinearLayout>
```

currently its display list, the problem is image background image

[image]

Requirement

1. select the radio button when listview load. that means first option should select

Comment: you can set the backgorund to listview if you go to XML that have your listview and use these android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"

Comment: I couldn't give list view on the top of <LinearLayout > This .. <ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/lists_header"
    android:background="@drawable/wallpaper" > <LinearLayout xmlns:android=..... > </LinearLayout ></listview>

Comment: Thank you. Its working fine now. But radio button selection have to do.

Comment: Thanks. Its background image setting working fine. Now the problem is highlight first row & select the radio button.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

make a style theme in values folder and add a windowBackground item to it and add that style to your layout xml